# Configuring Alternate Access mappings

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping, reverse-proxy

So this is the situation,

- I have a SharePoint farm with multiple servers.
- I have multiple web applications.
- I have two WFE servers.
- The incoming traffic is load balanced using an ISA server ( Reverse Proxy).
- Incoming traffic is secured using SSL (HTTPS, this is working fine, certificates are installed and the sites are accesible using the HTTPS adress.)

I have read a lot about AAM and I can still not figure out what the correct settings for my farm should be! Everything is working but I doubt that the settings are correct.

I have a site on port 80 which can be connected to by using http://WFE1 and http://WFE2. What I want however is that users can connect to it using SSL, so there is a rule in the ISA server that incoming requests on https://portal.company.com are routed to one of the two servers.

In AAM I now have the AAM set to https://portal.company.com for both internal and public url on the default zone. I am now able to connect to the site using https, but my question is if this setup is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct! You just need the one AAM for your HTTPS address, and you'll need IIS configured on both servers for SSL binding.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some more confidence in the set-up.